# VIM syntax folding : disable folding multi-line comments

Tags: c++, vim

I use the "syntax" foldmethod in vim 7.3. In .vimrc:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

When I open Test.cpp, containing:

```
/* A function with a multi-line
 * comment. This takes at least
 * four lines and I want to be
 * able to read all of them.
 */
void TheFunction()
{
  DoStuff();
}
```

I see the following when folded:

```
+--  5 lines: A function with a multi-line---------------------------------------------
void TheFunction() 
+--  3 lines: {------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I like the function body folding, but not the comment-folding. I want to disable it so it looks like this:

```
/* A function with a multi-line
 * comment. This takes at least
 * four lines and I want to be
 * able to read all of them.
 */
void TheFunction() 
+--  3 lines: {------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I do this? I can see the syntax group that's relevant with :syn list cComment

```
cComment       xxx matchgroup=cCommentStart start=+/\*+ end=+\*/+  extend fold contains
=@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cSpaceError,@Spell
                   links to Comment
```

But tooling around for an hour with the vim documentation and google hasn't told me how to remove the "fold" attribute from this group.

Is my only recourse really to edit the language syntax file? I suppose it's less ugly to copy the system syntax file and use this, but I should be able to turn off a specific group with a command in my .vimrc.

Comment: kev's answer works perfectly. This is found in the syn-file-remarks section of the docs `:help ft-c-syntax`. You can also fold `#if 0` style comments with `let c_no_if0_fold = 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `'foldmethod'` is set to `"syntax"` then `/* */ comments` and `{ } blocks` will
become a fold.  If you don't want comments to become a fold use:

```
:let c_no_comment_fold = 1
```