# Disable folding comments in vim

Tags: javascript, vim

Is there a way to disable folding for comments with `foldmethod=syntax` for Javascript files in vim?

I'm using the following folding code in my `vimrc`:

```
if has("folding")
    set foldenable
    set foldopen=hor,search,tag,undo
    set fillchars=diff:\ ,fold:\ ,vert:\

    function! JavaScriptFold()
            setl foldmethod=syntax
            setl foldlevelstart=1
            syn region foldBraces start=/{/ end=/}/ transparent fold keepend extend
    endfunction
endif
```

Calling `JavaScriptFold` folds the following code:

```
/**
 * Hello, this is a comment.
 */
function hello() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

into this:

```
+--  3 lines: *
+--  3 lines: function hello() {
```

I want it to get folded into this:

```
/**
 * Hello, this is a comment.
 */
+--  3 lines: function hello() {
```

I found out about `c_no_comment_fold` via [this Stack Overflow question on C comment folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038477/vim-syntax-folding-disable-folding-multi-line-comments), but I can't find an equivalent for Javascript. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which JavaScript syntax file do you use (the default? For which Vim version?)

Comment: I just want to ask same question as Ingos, if you set `fdm=syntax`, the folding rule was defined in syntax file. check the syntax file.

Comment: I'm using the [Javascript syntax file from this plugin](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax), and I'm using vim 7.3.

Comment: I didn't test, but you could give this a try:  `let javascript_ignore_javaScriptdoc=1` (in your vimrc). also you don't need that function in your vimrc.

Comment: > also you don't need that function in your vimrc.

Without copying it into my vimrc, I can't call it. I'm not sure what the problem is there, but I would love to solve that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available JavaScript syntax plugins are in a bad state. The one you're using is a bit weird (defining a function to enable (some) folding, with comment folding enabled by default), and has unused config variables (`javaScript_fold`, which does nothing).

To disable folding for comments, either directly edit the script and remove the `fold` keyword from the `syntax region javaScriptDocComment ...` line, or add the following redefinition to `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim`:

```
syntax clear javaScriptDocComment
syntax region javaScriptDocComment        matchgroup=javaScriptComment start="/\*\*\s*$"  end="\*/" contains=javaScriptDocTags,javaScriptCommentTodo,@javaScriptHtml,@Spell
```

Comment: Editing the `javaScriptDocComment` in the syntax plugin works, but adding the redefinition in `vimrc` does not work.

As an aside, the `javaScript_fold` variable seems to be related to some kind of default fold. It's also referenced in [this SO question about folding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789605/how-do-i-enable-automatic-folds-in-vim).

Comment: The `.vimrc` is sourced way too early, you need to use the `.vim/after/syntax` directory!

Comment: Oh, I missed that you mentioned `after/syntax`. Thanks!